# extension over $\Bbb{Q}$ corresponding to subgroups of $\Bbb{Z}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L$ be $\Bbb{Z}_p$-extension over $\Bbb{Q}$.
From infinite Galois theory, there is bijection between subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}_p$ and intermediate field of $L/\Bbb{Q}$.
Let $K_n$($n$ is fixed) be a intermediate field corresponding to the subgroup , $p^n\Bbb{Z}_p$.

If we write $K_n$ as simple extension, $\Bbb{Q(α)}$, then what can we take as $α$?

(For extension of $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$, correspoining extension field is explicitly written like $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^n})$)

Comment: Well, by the primitive element theorem *any* finite algebraic extension $K$ of $\mathbb Q$ can be written as $K=\mathbb Q(\alpha)$. You have to be a bit more precise with what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: What you you mean by a “bijection between $0$ and $p^n\mathbb Z_p.$” One is a number, one is an infinite set.

Answer (score 2):

For $p\ne 2$
$$K_n= \Bbb{Q}(\sum_{a=1}^{p-1} \zeta_{p^{n+1}}^{\textstyle a^{p^n}})$$
The proof uses that every subextension of a cyclotomic field is Galois, and that $K_n$ is the subfield of $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^{n+1}})$ fixed by $H_n = \{  \zeta_{p^{n+1}}\to \zeta_{p^{n+1}}^{\textstyle a^{p^n}},a\in 1\ldots p-1\}$ which is also $Tr_{\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^{n+1}})/\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^{n+1}})^{H_n}}(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^{n+1}}))$. This gives that $K_n = K_{n-1}(\sum_{a=1}^{p-1} \zeta_{p^{n+1}}^{\textstyle a^{p^n}})$. In particular $\sum_{a=1}^{p-1} \zeta_{p^{n+1}}^{\textstyle a^{p^n}}\not \in K_{n-1}$, and since $K_{n-1}$ contains all the subfields $\subsetneq K_n$ we get that $K_n=\Bbb{Q}(\sum_{a=1}^{p-1} \zeta_{p^{n+1}}^{\textstyle a^{p^n}})$.

For $p=2$
$$K_n=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{2^{n+2}}+\zeta_{2^{n+2}}^{-1})$$